# Access values from Object retrieve by REST callout

Tags: apex, rest-api, page-layout

I'm retrieving this response from a REST callout for Layouts and I want to access a current key of this Object:

This is how I managed response:

```
Map<String,Object> tokenResponse = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(body);
System.debug('*****pa1: ' + tokenResponse);
```

**body is:**

```
{"size":1,"totalSize":1,"done":true,"queryLocator":null,"entityTypeName":"ProfileLayout","records":[{"attributes":{"type":"ProfileLayout","url":"/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/ProfileLayout/01Gw000001F9kGrEAJ"},"Layout":{"attributes":{"type":"Layout","url":"/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/Layout/00hw00000
```

**and *****pa1:**

```
{done=true, entityTypeName=ProfileLayout, queryLocator=null, records=({Layout={Name=BI_Ciclo de ventas completo, attributes={type=Layout, url=/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/Layout/00hw000000QB6GSAA1}}, attributes={type=ProfileLayout, url=/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/ProfileLayout/01Gw000001F9kGrEAJ}}), size=1, totalSize=1}
```

**And I want to access **records -> [0] -> Layout -> attributes -> url**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation:

**IF clauses** are used to be sure that response contains all needed data.

*For example:
if tokenResponse does not contains key 'records', than it will throw null-pointer exception when retrieving it.*

Same for checking the size of the 'records' returned, because records[0] may not exist.

```
if (tokenResponse.containsKey('records')) {
    List<Object> records = (List<Object>) tokenResponse.get('records');
    
    if (records.size() > 0) {
        Map<String, Object> record  = (Map<String, Object>) records[0];
        
        if (record.containsKey('Layout')) {
            Map<String, Object> layout = (Map<String, Object>) record.get('Layout');

            if (layout.containsKey('attributes')) {
                Map<String, Object> attributes = (Map<String, Object>) layout.get('attributes');

                if (attributes.containsKey('url')) {
                    String url = (String) attributes.get('url');
                    system.debug(url);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```